# ABI.DECODE multiple swap data from 1inch

Tags: solidity

hello im trying make function for swapping multipple times in 1 function and i want input params this way that in python i encode them and inside function i decode some parameters(so function will have only 1 input parameter) and use them inside function but i have problem decode swap data , all other types like addres uint256 string decode without problem but when i decode swap data as bytes it output data which do not swap tokens heres is simple function how i m trying to do that :

```
function exec (bytes calldata params) external{
            (bytes memory swap_data,address token, uint256 amount) = abi.decode(params, (bytes, address,uint256)); 
            IERC20(token).approve(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V4, amount);      
            (bool succ,) = address(AGGREGATION_ROUTER_V4).call(swap_data);     
            require(succ, "Failed to swap" );
    }
```

i was also trying decode swap data as string and inside function convert them on bytes but it didnt work too

Comment: What does your input data look like? Are you sure that it is encoded according to the standard, so that `decode` can process it correctly.

Comment: Yes i encode it  in python with eth-abi library when i tried it with strings ,uint256, address as i said it works but only those bytes data didnt ... when i query from 1inch with python swap data it returns as string then i convert it into bytes this way : 

bytes(swap_data,'utf-8') 
and then i encode it this way with another parameters :
encode_abi(['bytes','address','uint256'], [swap_data,token,amount])      and function above work with token and amount but swap_data do not working for swap ....